# pandas to_datetime is very slow

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a decent sized sparse data frame with several date/time columns in string format.  I am trying convert them to datetime (or Timestamp) objects using the standard Pandas to_datetime() method.  But it is too slow.

I ended up writing a "fast" to_datetime function (below).  It is significantly faster, but it still seems slow.  Profiling tells me all of the time is spent on the last line.

Am I off the deep end?  Is there a different (and faster) way to do this?

```
In [98]: df.shape
Out[98]: (2497977, 79)

In [117]: len(df.reference_date.dropna())
Out[117]: 2004185

In [118]: len(df.reference_date.dropna().unique())
Out[118]: 157

In [119]: %time df.reference_date = pandas.to_datetime(df.reference_date)
CPU times: user 3min 2s, sys: 434 ms, total: 3min 2s
**Wall time: 3min 2s**

In [123]: %time fast_to_datetime(dataframe=df, column='reference_date', date_format='%Y%m%d')
CPU times: user 3.58 s, sys: 343 ms, total: 3.92 s
**Wall time: 3.92 s**


def fast_to_datetime(dataframe, column, date_format=None):
    tmp_dates = dataframe[column].dropna().unique()

    unique_dates = pandas.DataFrame(tmp_dates, columns=['orig_date'])
    unique_dates.set_index(keys=['orig_date'], drop=False, inplace=True, verify_integrity=True)

    unique_dates[column] = pandas.to_datetime(unique_dates.orig_date, format=date_format)

    dataframe.set_index(keys=column, drop=False, inplace=True)

    dataframe[column] = unique_dates[column]


In [126]: sys.version
Out[126]: '2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]'

In [127]: pandas.__version__
Out[127]: u'0.17.0'
```

Comment: Your `pandas` version looks pretty archaic to me. Try to upgrade to a more recent version (preferably `0.19`+) and see if that executes any faster.

Comment: I can't reproduce your timings on `pandas  0.19.2`.  Using similar input data (2.5 million rows, 500k nan, 157 unique date strings), I get `pd.to_datetime` taking 551 ms per loop, and `fast_to_datetime` taking 565 ms per loop. I verified that the output dates were identical for both methods.

Comment: @root did you do the assignment back to the original column (the last line of fast_to_datetime)?  That is where I am seeing most of the time be consumed.  I am not sure if this is a red herring, but  function_base.py:3384(delete) is taking 0.728 seconds per column.

Comment: @pjurgens Those timings did not include assigning back to the original columns, but I just tested it out, and doing so only added a few ms to each timing.